# Manga where the main character stalled for time inside a cave so that his fellow students could escape monsters, but got stuck inside himself

Tags: story-identification, manga

Can someone help me find this manga I read many years ago. I can’t remember anything about the characters, only the plot.

I vaguely remembered an event in this manga about the male main character (MC) following a female teacher to fight with strong monsters inside the cave, then he stalled for time till the other students escaped, but he got stuck inside.

In another event, the MC went to the lowest level underground and found a powerful (male?) demon torturing/killing one of strongest female knights that was recently appointed from the country. I am not so sure about this but I think there was a sword stuck on that female knight. I think the MC then received something from her, such as a pendent with her name on it.

I think no one know about the existence of demons before this.

It is not:

- Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Are you describing the same manga or two different ones here? If it's two different ones, you should post separate questions for each one. If it's the same one, was it mostly black & white or full colour? Also, what colour hair did the major female characters have?

Comment: I am not sure about this but hope it’s prob the same one. Sorry I can’t remember characteristic of any characters but only about the plot.

Comment: Okay. If anyone correctly identifies the manga you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Was the powerful demon male or female? If female, did that demon (or another demon) join the MC on his adventures? Or if not, do you recall what happens after he encounters this demon? Was this an isekai, one where the MC's entire class was summoned (including this teacher)? Do you recall if the MC had any special abilities, e.g. alchemy or crafting? (and do the other students all get normal-sounding combat abilities, and shun the MC?)

Comment: tbh I am not so sure about this but there was a sword stuck on that female knight. After Male(?) demon left, MC received something from female knight (maybe pendent with her name) that is why he identified her identity and back to report to the country afterwards. If you recall any manga which have similar storyline please do tell, I will go check one by one. Thanks

Comment: The manga I was thinking of was Arifureta, which involves the MC getting stuck in a cave. I'm a bit hazy on the details, but I know there was a female teacher and I think she was there at the time. Everything else doesn't sound like much of a match, especially the female knight stuff. Might be worth checking out just to see if you're mixing up multiple stories, but I'm pretty certain this isn't it.

Comment: Arifureta isn’t the one I’m looking for. I have read many Isekai’ed story in the past but this one was inside my mind for months sadly can’t seem to remembered the title T.T

Comment: Can you confirm if this is an isekai, and if it's in black&white or full color (i.e. is it a traditional Japanese Manga or a Chinese/Korean Webtoon)? This would help narrow down searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is chapter 119 of the manhwa “The Beginning After the End”.

From the description on [Tapas](https://m.tapas.io/series/tbate-comic/info):

> King Grey has unrivaled strength, wealth, and prestige in a world governed by martial ability. However, solitude lingers closely behind those with great power. Beneath the glamorous exterior of a powerful king lurks the shell of man, devoid of purpose and will.
>
> Reincarnated into a new world filled with magic and monsters, the king has a second chance to relive his life. Correcting the mistakes of his past will not be his only challenge, however. Underneath the peace and prosperity of the new world is an undercurrent threatening to destroy everything he has worked for, questioning his role and reason for being born again.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. It would help the rest of us to decide how likely this answer is to be correct, and whether we should therefore upvote it or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the manhwa you're looking for is ***[Talent Swallowing Magician](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/qvw2hie/demon-devourer)***.

> The descendant of a once great wizarding family, Elric Mervinger is unable to perform magic due to a rare medical condition. While attempting to cure his disease, he stumbles upon the demon Mephistopheles, who tries to possess Elric to free himself from a dragon's trap. But when Elric ends up absorbing Mephisto instead, the two become bound together. With Mephisto by his side, will this new power allow Elric to restore his family to its former glory? Or will he just end up being devoured?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you give us some details about this (maybe a link to it) and explain how it matches the question?  Since this question already has an accepted answer you need to justify why this is a better answer than the other one

Comment: It looks like this is referring to [재능 삼킨 마법사](https://page.kakao.com/content/58489471), which doesn't have an official English translation.